# Postgres GROUP BY id works on table directly, but not on identical view

Tags: postgresql, view

Lets say I have two tables. One of them references the other in a one-to-many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, name text
);

INSERT INTO t (name) VALUES ('one'), ('two'), ('three');

CREATE TABLE y (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, tid INTEGER REFERENCES t
, amount INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO y (tid, amount) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(3, 1);
```

I can query data from these tables in order to get `t` rows matching a certain condition set on `t` and `y`:

```
SELECT row_to_json(t.*) as "t_nogroup" FROM t
JOIN y ON t.id = y.tid
WHERE t.id = 1
AND y.amount > 1;
```

This yields

```
t_nogroup
=========
{"id":1,"name":"one"}
{"id":1,"name":"one"}
```

Which works, yes, but contains duplicates. I can filter out the duplicates by using a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT row_to_json(t.*) as "t_group" FROM t
JOIN y ON t.id = y.tid
WHERE t.id = 1
AND y.amount > 1
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Making:

```
t_group
=======
{"id":1,"name":"one"}
```

Great! However, when I try to exchange `t` and `y` for non-materialized `VIEW`s:

```
CREATE VIEW vt AS SELECT t.* FROM t;
CREATE VIEW vy AS SELECT y.* FROM y;
```

And run the same queries with the new `VIEW`s

```
SELECT row_to_json(vt.*) as "view_t_nogroup" FROM vt
JOIN vy ON vt.id = vy.tid
WHERE vt.id = 1
AND vy.amount > 1;

SELECT row_to_json(vt.*) as "view_t_group" FROM vt
JOIN vy ON vt.id = vy.tid
WHERE vt.id = 1
AND vy.amount > 1
GROUP BY vt.id;
```

I then get the error for the second query:

```
ERROR: column "vt.*" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Why does this happen? Whatever logic that saw that `*` contained `id` when using the table `t` should still work for the view `vt`, right?

Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/26b0e/5

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6. I'm also aware that this is a contrived example, but I am running into this error in a very similar one to many relation where multiple `GROUP BY` statements are needed and so just using `DISTINCT` isn't an option, like it would be for this example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem appears because Postgres knows that table `t` has `(id)` as the primary key - so we can use `GROUP BY t.id` and have more columns from that table in the `SELECT` list without aggregating them - but it can't infer the same for view `vt`.

For the examples provided, you can rewrite them as not to use `GROUP BY` at all. Since you don't need any column from the second joined table in the select list, you can convert the `JOIN` to an `EXISTS` subquery, i.e. convert the join to a semi-join. Now both the tables and views semijoin work without errors:

```
SELECT row_to_json(t.*) as "t_group" FROM t
WHERE t.id = 1 
  AND EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM y 
        WHERE t.id = y.tid
          AND y.amount > 1 
      ) ;

SELECT row_to_json(vt.*) as "t_group" FROM vt
WHERE vt.id = 1 
  AND EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM vy 
        WHERE vt.id = vy.tid
          AND vy.amount > 1 
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this works for the structure presented in the question/fiddle - but perhaps there are cases where group by is preferred?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (vt.id)
row_to_json(vt.*) FROM vt
JOIN vy ON vt.id = vy.tid
WHERE vt.id = 1
AND vy.amount > 1;
```

Comment: In this specific example, yes, `DISTINCT` works, but for any table more complex, the `DISTINCT` calculations are going to be _very_ slow. Thanks for the answer though!