# Select records and related entity count

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Given the following select that will count related entities for every record

```
SELECT MAIN.*, SUB.app_count
FROM my_table_view MAIN
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAIN2.p_key,
                       count(DISTINCT T3.app_id) AS app_count
                FROM my_table MAIN2
                         JOIN T1 ...
                         LEFT JOIN T2 ...
                         LEFT JOIN T3 ...
                GROUP BY MAIN2.p_key) SUB ON MAIN.p_key = SUB.p_key
WHERE ...
```

Trying to simplify it, came up with the following :

```
SELECT MAIN.p_key, count(DISTINCT T3.app_id) AS app_count -- select MAIN.* errors out - missing GROUP BY
FROM my_table_view MAIN
     LEFT JOIN T1 ON ...
     LEFT JOIN T2 ON ...
     LEFT JOIN T3 ON ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY MAIN.p_key
```

How to select all data from the `MAIN` table without adding a bunch of `GROUP BY`s ?
Would also appreciate performance hints.

#### Edit

I think this is related
[Postgres GROUP BY id works on table directly, but not on identical view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195104/postgres-group-by-id-works-on-table-directly-but-not-on-identical-view)

Comment: Remove GROUP BY at all. Use window version of COUNT(). Add DISTINCT for to remove duplicates from output rowset. PS. This is **NOT** a primary key - you must look at **query data source**, not at a particular table in it.

Comment: @Akina do you mind writing a response ?

Answer (score 0):

If `p_key` is the primary key of `my_table`, it should not be necessary to add the other columns, unless you want the statement to comply with the SQL standard.

Comment: p_key is the primary key but I select from a view

Comment: Then add all the columns to the `GROUP BY` clause. It is the safe and standard way.